# How can I save my Selenium IDE results in .xml format

Tags: selenium, ide

selenium-side-runner C:\SeleniumIDE\MyProjectOne.side  --output-directory C:\SeleniumIDE\Results  --output-format=junit

I followed the syntax provided https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner/#output-test-results-to-a-file but it gives me an error. In my command line I specify where the file should go but unable to execute. Please help. Sorry I am new to this and apologies if I am not clear on this issue.

I realize that when I put it this way in the command line selenium-side-runner C:\SeleniumIDE\MyProjectOne.side  --output-directory C:\SeleniumIDE\Results it does executes but stores format in .json file

Answer (score 0):

New here too.

According to the document URL you post, `--output-directory=results` should work. Your command line seems omit a `=` between `--output-directory` and `result`.

Try this:

```
selenium-side-runner C:\SeleniumIDE\MyProjectOne.side --output-directory=C:\SeleniumIDE\Results --output-format=junit
```

Also, if it still not work, since `result` means the out put file absolute or relative path, I'm wonder if putting quotation marks helps.

Try this:

```
selenium-side-runner C:\SeleniumIDE\MyProjectOne.side --output-directory="C:\SeleniumIDE\Results" --output-format=junit
```